# JPA 2.1 Converter Annotation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am using JPA 2.1 Converters so i annotate fields to be converted with @Convert.

Specification says that I should annotate my Converter class (implementation of AttributeConverter) with @Converter

> The Converter annotation specifies that the annotated class is a
>   converter and defines its scope. A converter class must be annotated
>   with the Converter annotation or defined in the XML descriptor as a
>   converter. *(from JSR 338: JavaTM Persistence API, Version 2.1
>   )*

But I noticed that the behaviour with @Converter annotation and without @Converter annotation is the same. The field is properly converted. Do I really need this annotation? What it is supposed to do?

Comment: I know that DataNucleus doesn't need this annotation present, since it loads whichever is referred to automatically. Which is your JPA provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javadoc at https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Converter.html says that it must be annotated so I would always do that. On the other hand some JPA provider may allow it without annotation but another one may not.

Comment: Yes, It seems to be provider issue.